# Python create multiple files out of one file

Tags: python, io

I am a Pyhton beginner and currently trying to write a small script that splits the lines of a file into a train and test set. The code generates for each `FOLD` two files (here 5*2), one train and one test file. The first train/test files (i.e. the first run through the loop) are generated problem-free and the other ones are created as well but they are empty. You can find my code snippet below:

```
for shuffledFile in os.listdir(INPUT_DIR_S):
with open(INPUT_DIR_S + shuffledFile, 'r') as inputFile:
    fold = 1
    pos = 0
    while fold <= FOLD:
        content = inputFile.readlines()
        step = len(content)/FOLD
        testSet = []
        trainSet = []
        for element in content[pos:step*fold]:
            testSet.append(element)
            content.remove(element)
        with open(create_folders(shuffledFile) + "/" + os.path.splitext(shuffledFile)[0] + "_TEST" + str(fold), 'w') as testFile:
            for result_line in testSet:
                testFile.write(str(result_line))
        for element in content:
            trainSet.append(element)
        with open(create_folders(shuffledFile) + "/" + os.path.splitext(shuffledFile)[0] + "_TRAIN" + str(fold), 'w') as trainFile:
            for result_line in trainSet:
                trainFile.write(str(result_line))
        fold += 1
        pos += step
```

I also used the debugger and saw that there is a problem with `content`, because it is empty after the first iteration.
But I do not know why this happens and what I actually have to do to fix it. This is probably a really basic and simple question for those familiar with Python, and I would really appreciate it if someone can explain me what's the actual issue. Thank you all for your time and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File objects behave like iterators over lines in a file. When you call `readlines()` on a file object, all of the items from the iterator are consumed. Subsequent calls to `readlines()` on the same file object will return an empty list.

So if you need to iterate over the lines of a file multiple times, you will need to reset the iterator or to store the list of lines returned by the first call to `readlines()` in a separate variable and iterate over it as many times as you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I was able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want 4/5th of data to be train and 1/5th test, if you randomize your data, it's a matter of splitting entire dataset once:

```
import random
lines = open("...").readlines()
random.shuffle(lines)
fold = len(lines)/5
train = lines[:-fold]
test = lines[-fold:]
```